# How to Sum Column (A) and Column (B) split into B and B2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Existing Data. EMP001 has two records in 2017. I want to convert to 1 line where column Sum(A) and Column split into two columns.

```
EMP_NO  |   A       |   B       |   C
--------|-----------|-----------|---------   
EMP001  |   2000    |   200     |   2017A
EMP001  |   3000    |   39      |   2017B
EMP002  |   50      |   20      |   2017B
```

I want to get result as below.

```
EMP_NO  |   A       |   B       |   B2
--------|-----------|-----------|---------
EMP001  |   5000    |   200     |   39      
EMP002  |   50      |   20      |   0
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please tag it.

Comment: What's the expected result if there are three rows with same EMP_NO?

Comment: I using MSSQL. There are only 2 rows in each year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this for just two columns:

```
SELECT SUM(A) AS A,
       MAX(B) AS B,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 2 THEN MIN(B) ELSE 0 END AS B2
  FROM EMP001
 GROUP BY emp_no
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff thanks for the edit. I assumed no explicit order were required, but this solution is better

Answer (score 1):

I used CTE, RANK , UNION statments to combine right rows.
First union block collects A column, the second B column, the last one B2 column. CTE is used only to improve readability.

```
    ;WITH CTE(EMP_no, B, RNK)
    AS
    (
        SELECT  EMP_no, 
                B,                  
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_no  ORDER BY  rn ) AS RNK 
        FROM    (
                    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMP_no ) as RN, 
                            EMP_no,
                            b                               
                    FROM    Test ) AS X             
    )
    SELECT  EMP_no,
            SUM(A) AS A,
            SUM(B) AS B,
            SUM(B2) AS B2
    FROM    (
                SELECT  EMP_no, 
                        A,
                        0 AS B,
                        0 AS B2
                FROM    Test
                    UNION ALL
                SELECT  EMP_no,
                        0,
                        CTE.B,
                        0
                FROM    CTE 
                WHERE CTE.RNK = 1
                    UNION ALL
                SELECT  EMP_no,
                        0,
                        0,
                        CTE.B
                FROM    CTE 
                WHERE CTE.RNK = 2
            ) AS X
    GROUP BY x.EMP_no
```

Answer (score 0):

use Pivot table for getting the result

```
SELECT emp_no, sum(a),sum(isnull([2017],0)) as b ,sum(isnull([2017b],0))   
as b1
FROM 
(SELECT emp_no,a,b,c
 FROM test ) ps
 PIVOT
       (
          max(b) FOR c
                IN
                  ( [2017],[2017b])
       ) AS pvt
 group by emp_no;
```